# gprof: unexpected EOF after reading 48/271618093 bins?

Tags: gcc, gprof

Does anyone know what this error means for `gprof`? I'm running `gcc -pg`. Thanks.

Comment: What platform? Also did you mean `samples` instead of `bins`?

Comment: `crystalball: command not found`

Comment: Can't help you if all you want to do is run gprof. If you want to find performance problems, [do this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell with so little information. This can happen in particular if you messed up with the arguments you're giving to `gprof`, as reported [here](http://bugs.opensolaris.org/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4721443) (which was hard to find, because it's only Google's 2nd hit for your question's title).

**Edit:** so, double check your arguments. If you want us to check them for you, report the command-line you used, and how the various files were generated. As a rule: ***we can't guess***.

Answer (score 6):

As this question is the top result on Google :

You probably ran gprof the wrong way
compile with the -pg flag
execute your binary
it will also output a "gmon.out" file

then run :

```
gprof {executable} gmon.out > profile
```

the "profile" file should contain the results of gprof

Comment: +1. I think (not sure) that the issue is that if your program is not called `a.out`, gprof will give up unless you tell it the explicit executable file.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem. I was running gprof directly after compiling the code on the executable. We need to do the following:

1. Compile the code using -pg -g option as follows:

   gcc -g -pg myfile.c -o myfile.out
2. Run the executable without using gprof first (The first run creates gmon.out)

   myfile.out 100 200 400 % where 100, 200 and 400 are my input parameters to myfile.out
3. Step 2 creates gmon.out by default. You need to feed this and the executable to gprof to create the runtime profile of the executable.

   gprof myfile.out gmon.out % redirect this to a file

The file will contain  the executable profile.